# Elasticsearch - use a field match to boost only and not to fetch the document

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a query phrase that needs to match in either of the fields - `name`, `summary` or `description` or the exact match on the `name` field.

Now, I have one more new field `brand`. Match in this field should be used only to boost results. Meaning if there is a match only in the `brand` field, the doc should not be in the result set.

To solve the without `brand` I have the below query:

```
query: {
   bool: {
      minimum_should_match: 1,
      should: [
         multi_match:{
             query : "Cadbury chocklate milk",
             fields : [name, summary, description]
         },
         term: {
             name_keyword: {
                value: "Cadbury chocklate milk"
             }
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

This works fine for me.

How do I fetch the data using the same query but boost docs that have `brand:cadbury`, without increasing the recall set(match based on `brand:cadbury`).

Thanks!

Comment: if there is no match in the brand , do you still want to return with the existing query ?

Comment: yes. Consider the match in the brand is used just to boost results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a `bool` inside must `should` work for you.

`multi_match` has multiple types and for phrase you have to use `type:phrase`.

```
{
  "query": {
   "bool": {
      "must": [
         { "bool" : 
      { "should" : [ {
         "multi_match" :{
            "type" : "phrase",
             "query" : "Cadbury chocklate milk",
             "fields" : ["name", "summary", "description"]
         }  }, {
         "term": {
             "name_keyword": {
                "value": "Cadbury chocklate milk"
             }  }
         }
      ]
      }   
    } 
  ],
   "should" :  {
     "term" : {
          "brand" :  { 
        "value" :  "cadbury"
       }
    }
  }

}
}
```

Comment: The second should query doesn't add anything to score :( So, order is unchanged. 
Upon looking up the explain I don't see `brand:cadbury` match anyhwere

Comment: Can you show your mapping? What is the type of brand field.

Comment: It's `keyword`  Does it need to be text and analysed?

Comment: If it is saved as keyword and the value is **cadbury**, then you have to search exactly for cadbury. Case should be same and value should also be same. For keywords, use terms queries as in answer.

Comment: stupid ‍♂️ It was `Cadbury` in the index.